# ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE - Web Bluetooth API

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

Client Configuration Characteristic Descriptor (CCCD).

UUID - "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" / 'gatt.client_characteristic_configuration'.

To set CCCD in Java code for Android
we do:

```
public static final byte[] ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE = {0x01, 0x00};

BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor =    characteristic.getDescriptor("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

How can I perform a similar configuration in JavaScript code when using the Web Bluetooth API ?

My version in JavaScript:

```
.then(descriptors => {    
let queue = Promise.resolve();
 descriptors.forEach(descriptor => {
        switch (descriptor.uuid) {    
          case BluetoothUUID.getDescriptor('gatt.client_characteristic_configuration'):
           queue = queue.then(_ => descriptor.readValue()).then(value => {
              descriptorCache = descriptor;
            });
   ...

    var data = new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00]);
    descriptorCache.writeValue(data);
    //descriptorCache.writeValue(new TextEncoder().encode(data));
```

fails with a security error :-(

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: writeValue() called on blocklisted object marked exclude-writes. 
https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#attacks-on-devices

I understand the need for security.
But after all, a lot of devices require a presetting of the CCCD.

Answer (score 2):

Calling [`characteristic.StartNotifications()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetoothremotegattcharacteristic-startnotifications) sets the CCCD for you.